# Spring boot disable filter log

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I see logging message kind of below.

```
/api/1/0/abc at position 1 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
/api/1/0/abc at position 2 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistentFilter'
/api/1/0/abc at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
/api/1/0/abc at position 5 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
/api/1/0/abc at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
    /api/1/0/abc at position 6 of 9 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAutenticationFilter'
```

All the security filter log i want to disable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the logging level on the filters you can simply add to your application level.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter=ERROR
```

You have the following options to set the log level to:

`ERROR, WARN, INFO, DEBUG, TRACE`

Comment: Thank man.  Yes, I see it is supported from the 2.1.1 RELEASE. I have two application in one this kind of log is coming and in another one this kind of logs is not coming. Do you have any clue why log is coming  ?

Comment: I would have a look the property files - just check that the logging level is not disabled higher up the hierarchy. example: logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR will reduce the logging of loads of things. ps. Please ask any new questions in a question :) thanks